# Using one component in several places with different logic (with formic)

Tags: reactjs

I have a large display component (react js)

It has several InputText fields whose logic is managed using [FORMIK](https://formik.org/docs/overview)

I am interested in using the component in several places

But everywhere I want the logic to be different

For example in the part that will only be readOnly or something like that

I thought of using the component several times and each time giving it an object of a different formic

Is this possible?

Is there a smarter solution to this problem

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the React [Container Component](https://reactpatterns.com/#container-component) Pattern. Logic in container component, UI in a presentational component. Different containers can render the same presentational component but pass different prop values. The tricky business is stepping back enough to think of your UI abstractly enough to not simply expose out a bunch of one-off use-case props. [This](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) article by Dan Abramov also helps explain.

Comment: Give some code examples..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found

This is certainly possible with the help of [withFormik](https://formik.org/docs/api/withFormik)

In this example I used one component twice at a time with different logic

Different start values

Different scheme

And onSubmit is different

Attaches a sample code

```
 <Component
        initialData={data.own}
        handleSubmit={onSubmitOwn}
        validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
          username: Yup.string().required("Username is required!")
        })}
  <Component
          initialData={data.tow}
          handleSubmit={onSubmitTow}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            password: Yup.string().required("Password is required!")
          })}
        />
```

```
export default withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: props => {
    return {
      username: props.initialData.username
    };
  },

  validationSchema: props => props.validationSchema,

  handleSubmit: (values, { props, setSubmitting }) => {
    props.handleSubmit(values);
  }
})(Component);
```

[image: Edit new]